# Iterating through the elements returned by getElementsByClassName and changing the .className attribute produces weird behavior

Tags: javascript

Suppose I call getElementsByClassName() and store the result in a variable like so:

```
var editButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("editButtonDisabled");
```

Then I iterate through that variable (which is a nodelist, so `.item(i)` is used and not `[i]`) and change the class name of each item:

```
for (var i = 0; i < editButtons.length; i++) {

    var editButton = editButtons.item(i);
    editButton.className = "editButtonEnabled";

}
```

For some reason the loop skips over all the odd-indexed members of `editButtons` and only applies the class name change to the even-numbered ones, as though the length of `editButtons` is being mutated by changing the properties of its members, which shouldn't be the expected behavior in my opinion.

I know I can get around this by just throwing all the elements into an array first and then looping through it again, but that requires writing two loops when only one should be necessary, and I'm curious as to why it's doing this in the first place.

Comment: That's what happens when you work with live collections, iterate in reverse to solve the issue

Comment: Cool thanks that explained and solved it

Answer (score -1):

Yes, because `editButtons.length` changes after each iteration, you should put the length in a variable:

```
for (var i = 0, length = editButtons.length; i < length; i++) {
    var editButton = editButtons.item(i);

    editButton.className = "editButtonEnabled";

}
```

**EDIT:**

I was wrong about my solution and about length.
In fact when the `first button` class is changes the button is popped out of the array and when the `i` is incremented the `second button` (witch now is at index 0) is skipped and so on.

The solution is to iterate in reverse:

```js
function changeClassName() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('editButtonDisabled');

  for (var i = buttons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var button = buttons[i];

    button.className = 'editButtonEnabled';
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
.editButtonDisabled {
  background: red;
}
.editButtonEnabled {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeClassName()">changeClassName()</button>

<button class="editButtonDisabled">Button 01</button>
<button class="editButtonDisabled">Button 02</button>
<button class="editButtonEnabled">Button 03</button>
<button class="editButtonDisabled">Button 04</button>
<button class="editButtonDisabled">Button 05</button>
<button class="editButtonDisabled">Button 06</button>
<button class="editButtonEnabled">Button 07</button>
<button class="editButtonDisabled">Button 08</button>
<button class="editButtonDisabled">Button 09</button>
<button class="editButtonDisabled">Button 10</button>
```

Comment: That's not enough; you're still skipping the changed indices.

Comment: I'm more curious as to why editButtons.length changes. Since I'm not calling `getElementsByClassName()` again, the variable that stored the original nodelist returned by it shouldn't have had its length changed, I would expect.

Comment: @joeyp every time you change the class name of a button, the button is removed from the array and the array gets smaller. But my idea was wrong. I updated my answer with a reverse iteration example